# Print html contents directly using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, printing

**Code Snippet from jquery**

```
$.post("GetData",{

     itemCode:getItemCode

    }, function(html) {

         //want to Print to a printer directly html contents using jquery 

    });
```

I want to directly print, to a printer, the servlet response, which is type of html.

How can we do this? Is there is any jquery plugin available to do this ? or there are some tricks to do this?

Comment: Print to the screen, or to a printer..?

Comment: Are you talking about logging the HTML response or inserting the HTML into the DOM?

Comment: There's a jQuery plugin on this page that you could probably use to print that content. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice jQuery plugin to do that: [jqPrint](https://github.com/tanathos/jquery.jqprint)